# XSLT XPATH : Within a Collection of XHTML files, for a given XHTML : change the title node content to the XHTML filename

Tags: xslt, xpath

I got a bunch of files dummy*.xhtml with the title node containing : title XHTML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" type="text/css" xml:space="preserve"/>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
    <title>title XHTML</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Dummy</p>
</body>
</html>
```

For each file, I need to replace the content of the node title with its filename.

If the file is dummy.xhtml, the title node content should become : dummy.xhtml

I tried the following XSLT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                exclude-result-prefixes="h">
            
                
    <xsl:output method="xhtml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" standalone="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>   
    </xsl:template>

    
    <xsl:template match="h:title">
          <title>
                <!-- <xsl:value-of select="$xhtml_name"/> -->
          </title>
    </xsl:template>
    

    <xsl:template match="/">
    
        <xsl:for-each select="collection('?select=dummy*.xhtml')">
        
            <xsl:variable name="xhtml_name">
                    <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(base-uri(), '/')[last()]"/>
            </xsl:variable>
                    
            <xsl:message>xhtml_name : <xsl:value-of select="$xhtml_name"/></xsl:message>

            
            <xsl:variable name="path_to_cleaned">
                <xsl:value-of select="iri-to-uri(replace(document-uri(current()), '.xhtml', '.cleaned.xhtml'))"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            
            
            <xsl:message>path_to_cleaned : <xsl:value-of select="$path_to_cleaned"/></xsl:message>


            <xsl:result-document indent="yes" method="xhtml" href="{$path_to_cleaned}">
                <xsl:apply-templates/> 
            </xsl:result-document>
            
        </xsl:for-each>
            
    </xsl:template>

    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I got trapped because the variable $xhtml_name is local to : template match="/".

Then with doubt, I tried to define the variable $xhtml_name and insert the collection within to kind of make it global.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                exclude-result-prefixes="h">
            
                
    <xsl:output method="xhtml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" standalone="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>   
    </xsl:template>

    
    <xsl:template match="h:title">
          <title>
                <xsl:value-of select="$xhtml_name"/>
          </title>
    </xsl:template>
    

    <xsl:variable name="xhtml_name">
        
        <xsl:for-each select="collection('?select=dummy*.xhtml')">

            <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(base-uri(), '/')[last()]"/>
        

            <xsl:variable name="path_to_cleaned">
                <xsl:value-of select="iri-to-uri(replace(document-uri(current()), '.xhtml', '.cleaned.xhtml'))"/>
            </xsl:variable>

            <xsl:message>path_to_cleaned : <xsl:value-of select="$path_to_cleaned"/></xsl:message>


            <xsl:result-document indent="yes" method="xhtml" href="{$path_to_cleaned}">
                <xsl:apply-templates/> 
            </xsl:result-document>

        </xsl:for-each> 

    </xsl:variable>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As expected it does not work and returns errors.

How to achieve this ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a tunnel parameter e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="h:title">
      <xsl:param name="xhtml_name" tunnel="yes"/>
      <title>
            <xsl:value-of select="$xhtml_name"/>
      </title>
</xsl:template>
```

you pass on in your first sample in the line

```
        <xsl:result-document indent="yes" method="xhtml" href="{$path_to_cleaned}">
            <xsl:apply-templates>
               <xsl:with-param name="xhtml_name" tunnel="yes" select="$xhtml_name"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:result-document>
```

Note than several lines in your XSLT can be simplified and shortened by making use of the `xpath-default-namespace` and the use of `<xsl:variable name="foo" select="expression"/>` instead of `<xsl:variable name="foo"><xsl:value-of select="expression"/></xsl:variable>`.

Comment: Thank you so much Martin, it is woking fine. A new function added to my learning. You are right for the variable definition, it is lighter so better. For the xpath-default-namespace, I am really a noob in this area. Will your suggestion remove the xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" from <title xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">dummy.xhtml</title> that appears in the cleaned file?

Comment: @Bin31, if you are dealing with XHTML elements for all or most templates and XPath selections it is shorter and easier to declare `<xsl:stylesheet xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ...>` up front as then you don't need a prefix to match and select the XHTML elements e.g. any `match="h:title"` becomes `match="title"`.

Comment: So basically : <xsl:stylesheet xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" > is enough, correct ?

Comment: I noticed that there is some leftover xmlns="" in <title xmlns="">00000286.0002001_css.cleaned.xhtml</title>, may be I was not absolutely correct in my here above post.

Comment: For the selection and matching you only need the `xpath-default-namespace`, to create new result XHTML elements you will also need to declare `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`, but you had  that in your original code.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation Martin, it is clearer now.